403 forbidden error in Spring Security even after authenticating and authorizing
I've defined three entities: User, Job, Profile, and an enumeration UserType.
I created an AdminController for REST APIs to post jobs, return all users, return a job by specific ID, return a user by specific ID, etc. All admin endpoints are authenticated and authorized for users with the admin role only. I predefined two users in my UserService class.
The issue I'm encountering is that when I try to access one of the admin endpoints ("/admin/applicants") through Postman, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error even after authenticating with the credentials username:Admin and password:Admin.
Security cofig file
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImp;


    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImp) {
        this.userDetailsServiceImp = userDetailsServiceImp;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/signup", "/login", "/jobs")
                            .permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .requestMatchers( "/uploadResume").hasRole("APPLICANT")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                }).userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImp)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

Admin controller file
@RestController
public class AdminController {
    @Autowired
    private JobService jobService;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    
    @PostMapping("/admin/job")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createJob(@RequestBody Job job) {
        Job createdJob = jobService.saveJob(job);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdJob);
    }

    
    @GetMapping("/admin/job/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getJobById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Job job = jobService.findJobById(id);
        if (job == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(job);
    }

    
    @GetMapping("/admin/applicants")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllApplicants() {
        List<User> applicants = userRepository.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(applicants);
    }

    
    @GetMapping("/admin/applicant/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> applicantId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            Long userId = user.getUserId();
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userId);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
}

User service file
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public User registerUser(User user) {
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        savedUser.setPasswordHash(passwordEncoder.encode(savedUser.getPasswordHash()));


        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setUserName("Admin");
        user1.setPasswordHash(passwordEncoder.encode("Admin"));
        user1.setRole(UserType.ADMIN);

        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setUserName("Applicant");
        user2.setPasswordHash(passwordEncoder.encode("Applicant"));
        user2.setRole(UserType.APPLICANT);


        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.save(user2);


        return savedUser;
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName){
        return userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    }
}

User detail service implementation
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImp(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByUserName(userName)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }
}

This is the Auth controller where users can sign up
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody User user){
        if(user == null || user.getUserName() == null || user.getEmail() == null ||  user.getAddress() == null || user.getRole() == null || user.getPasswordHash() == null || user.getProfileHeadline() == null ){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid Input");
        }
        User savedUser = userService.registerUser(user);
        if(savedUser != null){
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Signup Successful");
        }
        else{
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Failed to Signup");
        }

Postman error of 403 after authenticating
Tried adding @PreAuthroize annotation in some endpoints but still didnt work.
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
I'm only able to access the endpoint when I remove all the security configurations.

for your users to be created someone needs to trigger the method registerUser() - you sure it has been called BEFORE you tried accessing the /admin/applicants?

Yes, i have another controller where users can sign up and registerUser() is being used to register the users. I have just updated the post and you can have look.

ok, provided that is the case (I would have just put registerUser() in some @PostConstruct method for now), you need to know WHY you are getting 403, set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG so that you see the error. After that paste the error into question

I don't see any authentication configured. How do you login? There is no formLogin, no httpBasicor oauthLogin.

@dur thanks for pointing this out. I was missing the authentication configuration, after adding httpBasic in my code and modifying it a bit, the code now works and I can authenticate it without any 403 error.

@JAsgarov I didnt knew we could debug spring security configuration through logs. It does show now the details of the error, Thanks for letting me know about this logging.

You have to use ROLE_ prefix with roles (considering that User class is defined by you and not a User class provided by spring security )
something like this :
User user1 = new User();
        user1.setUserName("Admin");
        user1.setPasswordHash(passwordEncoder.encode("Admin"));
        user1.setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");

